# Parsing JSON result from web link

Tags: c#, json, string, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

I'm trying to string data from this JSON [Link](https://api.dell.com/support/v2/assetinfo/warranty/tags.json?svctags=G88NJX1&apikey=1adecee8a60444738f280aad1cd87d0e) Click on Link to view

Using JSON.NET. Im able to Deserialize and string the entire thing. But what I need is just values of below

```
    "Warranty":[
      {
        "EndDate": "ValueIWant",
        "ServiceLevelDescription": "ValueIWant"
      },
```

There should be  4 warranty entries from which I need EndDate & ServiceLevelDescription for all and list it in a Multi Line Text box.

Edited: Final Working code

```
        string Serial = "G88NJX1";
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        Stream stream = client.OpenRead("https://api.dell.com/support/v2/assetinfo/warranty/tags.json?svctags=" + Serial + "&apikey=1adecee8a60444738f280aad1cd87d0e");
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
        var jObject = JObject.Parse(reader.ReadLine());

        foreach (var o in jObject["GetAssetWarrantyResponse"]["GetAssetWarrantyResult"]["Response"]["DellAsset"]["Warranties"]["Warranty"])
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Warranty end date: {0}", (string)o["EndDate"]);
            Console.WriteLine("Warranty service level description: {0}", (string)o["ServiceLevelDescription"]);

        }

        Console.ReadLine();
        stream.Close();
```

Comment: I do not want to use a service reference for this.

Comment: I am beeing trying to figure this out for ages, thank you!  But you should censor your api key so others can't use it!  :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use json.net to parse the json only, rather than deserialize it, then you can query the parsed data, using linq or otherwise. Details [here](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm).

This code snippet works in linqpad to output the two values you want from your example json.

```
var json = @"{'Warranty':[{'EndDate':'ValueIWant','ServiceLevelDescription':'ValueIWant'}]}";

var j = JObject.Parse(json);

foreach(var o in j["Warranty"])
{
    Console.WriteLine("Warranty end date: {0}", (string)o["EndDate"]);
    Console.WriteLine("Warranty service level description: {0}", (string)o["ServiceLevelDescription"]);
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what i needed. Updated my post to show the exact code i used

Comment: Now that v2 doesn't work, did you ever upgrade your code to v4?  I am unable to figure out how to parse it.

Comment: @JonWeinraub I'm not sure what you mean? the snippet worked fine for me in linqpad v5 with json.net v12

Comment: I meant v4 of the Dell Warranty.  v2 links don't work anymore and the json structure is completely different.

Comment: @JonWeinraub no, I don't have api key or appropriate service tags to make calls to the api. Navigating the json object graph should be straight forward anyway.